# How to initialize a vector with an explicit element initializer?

Tags: c++

We can use the following syntax to initialize a vector.

```
// assume that UserType has a default constructor
vector<UserType> vecCollections;
```

Now, if UserType doesn't provide a default constructor for UserType but only a constructor as follows:

```
explicit UserType::UserType(int i) { ... }.
```

How should I call this explicit element initializer with the vector constructor?

Comment: +1 for the question, as it made me to write a initializer, which I eventually liked :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
vector<UserType> vecCollections(10, UserType(2));
```

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there is no way in current C++ (C++03) to initialize the vector with arbitrary elemtnts. You can initialize it with one and the same element as in @Erik's answer.

However in C++0x you can do it. It is called an `initializer_list`

```
vector<UserType> vecCollections({UserType(1), UserType(5), UserType(10)});
```

Incidentally, you might want to check out the [boost::assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/assign/doc/index.html) library, which is a very syntactically convenient way to assign to a vector and other containers

Comment: Even in C++03, you can initialize vector with arbitrary types! See my solution!

Comment: @Nawaz: I believe that's boost assign's solution :)

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<char> items(10, 'A'); //initialize all 10 elements with 'A'
```

However, if you want to initialize the vector with *different* values, then you can write a generic *vector initializer* class template, and use it everywhere:

```
template<typename T>
struct initializer
{
   std::vector<T> items;
   initializer(const T & item) { items.push_back(item); }
   initializer& operator()(const T & item) 
   {
      items.push_back(item);
      return *this;
   }
   operator std::vector<T>&() { return items ; }
};

int main() {
        std::vector<int> items(initializer<int>(1)(2)(3)(4)(5));
        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < items.size() ; i++ )
           std::cout << items[i] << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Demo at ideone: http://ideone.com/9dODD

Comment: +1 I believe this is what [boost::assign::list_of](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/assign/doc/index.html#list_of) does too.

Comment: why not overload the command-operator it would look much nicer.

Comment: just a smarter way to use operator(). This is real fancy:)